Establish SSL/TLS connection to AWS RDS MySQL with GoLang/Docker
I'm trying to establish SSL/TLS connection to AWS RDS MySQL. The server is build in Docker and I can't force it to use certificate bundle provided by AWS...
When I run the service in Docker container I receive first ERROR:
2024/05/31 11:08:16 /app/internal/services/servicecontainer.go:252 driver: bad connection
and with each interaction with DB I receive:
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match host.docker.internal
and this is while run locally. If I try same in AWS I get:
failed to initialize database, got error Error 3159: Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON
According to AWS docs. The SSL/TLS certificate includes the DB instance endpoint as the Common Name (CN) for the SSL/TLS certificate to guard against spoofing attacks.
How should I specify CN in my code or what else should I do to establish secure connection?
Thank you for your help!
Docker file:
FROM golang:1.22 

# BUILD CODE I BELIEVE IS NOT RELEVANT
    
ADD ./internal/certificates /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates

CMD ["./main"]

GoLang code:
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "database/sql"
    "os"
    "sync"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"

    mysqlDriver "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func InitializeKernel() *ControllerService {

    DB_HOST := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    DB_DBNAME := os.Getenv("DB_DBNAME")
    DB_CREDENTIALS := os.Getenv("DB_CREDENTIALS")

    AWS_REGION := os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")
    if AWS_REGION == "" {
        AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
    }


    var dbCred dbCredentials

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(DB_CREDENTIALS), &dbCred)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not parse db credentials from env")
    }

    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    globPem, err := os.ReadFile("./internal/certificates/global-bundle.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(globPem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append global PEM.")
    }

    mysqlDriver.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: rootCertPool,
    })

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:3306)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&tls=custom&loc=Local", dbCred.Username, dbCred.Password, DB_HOST, DB_DBNAME)
    customDb, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{
        Conn: customDb,
    }), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return &ControllerService{Db: db, DynamoDb: dynamoDb}
}

I've searched for solution and found next information:

Issue with golang function for verification of CN name: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/248
AWS documentation about using TLS connection: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.CertificatesAllRegions
Stack issue: How to use the go-mysql-driver with ssl on aws with a mysql rds instance
GoLang Gorm docs: https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html
GoLang driver docs: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#parameters


It turned out that this code (has room for improvements :)) is not working in local environment only.
For production (meaning it should run on AWS) I had to change host name from host.docker.internal to RDS DB endpoint.
I'm gonna fully test and confirm it next week, but for now it seems fully functional in QA environment.
I tested it in dev, qa and prod and it works.
Below you can find the code itself:
package services

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"

    mysqlDriver "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "onestop.com/requests/internal/controllers"
    "onestop.com/requests/internal/repositories"
)

type dbCredentials struct {
    Password             string
    Dbname               string
    Engine               string
    Port                 int
    DbInstanceIdentifier string
    Host                 string
    Username             string
}


type ControllerService struct {
    Db       *gorm.DB
}

func InitializeKernel() *ControllerService {

    dbHOST := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    dbNAME := os.Getenv("DB_DBNAME")
    dbCREDENTIALS := os.Getenv("DB_CREDENTIALS")

    var dbCred dbCredentials

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dbCREDENTIALS), &dbCred)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not parse db credentials from env")
    }

    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    globPem, err := os.ReadFile("./internal/certificates/global-bundle.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(globPem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append global PEM.")
    }

    mysqlDriver.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: rootCertPool,
    })

    tlsOpt := "custom"
    // change TLS option for local development
    if dbHOST == "host.docker.internal" {
        tlsOpt = "skip-verify"
    }

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:3306)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&tls=%s&loc=Local", dbCred.Username, dbCred.Password, dbHOST, dbNAME, tlsOpt)
    customDb, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{
        Conn: customDb,
    }), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return &ControllerService{Db: db}
}

I use tls=skip-verify for local environment and tls=custom for qa and prod.
Gorm driver for MySQL don't support custom certificates but it can accept connection from custom library. Probably it may influence performance however (didn't check)
